# Change integer date format to pandas date format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'date': {0: 20210101, 1: 20210102, 2: 20210103, 3: 20210104, 4: 20210105},
 'users_with_pdp': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}}
```

I would like these dates in the following format: d-m-yyyy.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Try to get date format in pandas

Comment: `df` is a dictionary or a DataFrame?

Comment: df is a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

> From a dataframe:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%d%m').dt.strftime('%-d-%-m-%Y')
print(df)

# Output
       date  users_with_pdp
0  1-1-2021               1
1  1-2-2021               2
2  1-3-2021               3
3  1-4-2021               4
4  1-5-2021               5
```

---

You can use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
# This is a dict not a dataframe!
df = {0: 20220101, 1: 20220102, 2: 20220103, 3: 20220104, 4: 20220105}

sr = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df), format='%Y%m%d')
print(sr)

# Output
0   2022-01-01
1   2022-01-02
2   2022-01-03
3   2022-01-04
4   2022-01-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Update**

> If I want to adjust it to DD-MM-YYYY?

> I want to change dd-mm-yyyy date value to d-m-yyyy format

```
sr = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df), format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%-d-%-m-%Y')
print(sr)

# Output
0    1-1-2022
1    2-1-2022
2    3-1-2022
3    4-1-2022
4    5-1-2022
dtype: object
```

**Caveat**: you will lost the DatetimeIndex object and get string.

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to adjust it to DD-MM-YYYY ?

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Nvm, I already got it. Had to select column in original dataframe. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Typo: I changed df1 to df

Comment: One more question: I want to change dd-mm-yyyy date value to d-m-yyyy format, in case that the days and months are single digit. How would this be possible?

Comment: Could you please adjust this in the code? I get the following format: 2022-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: Apologies. How would the code be adjusted if it regards a dataframe?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to convert it in a pandas dataframe

Comment: Your input dict is a dataframe or you want the series become a dataframe?

Comment: I provided the dictionary as an example. How can only a column in the dataframe that is called 'date' be transfered into the followign date format: '%-d-%-m-%Y'. I will provide the head of the dataframe in dictionary format.

Comment: As mentioned, the dictionary that I provided is the head of the original dataframe

Comment: It should be right now.

Comment: ValueError: unconverted data remains: 3

Comment: You have bad formatted date like 202101053 (3 for what? hours?)

Comment: Try: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%d%m', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%-d-%-m-%Y')` and find nan value in Date column.

Comment: I have no idea?\

Comment: It is somehow not possible to convert to %-d-%-m-%Y

Comment: Yes it's possible but you have to check and clean your data first... You have wrong dates in your dataframe, delete or ignore them but you have to do something

Comment: Corralien's answer is correct, if you have issues with it the problem likely lies somewhere else. Please provide a reproducible example that triggers an error if you have any.